# FormData SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 at JSON

Tags: angular, multipartform-data

My front server is Angular6

BackServer is express

When i tring to post formdata to backserver

The file is upload successful.

But i get this error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at XMLHttpRequest.onLoad (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:2289:51)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:31)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4967:33)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:36)
    at Zone.runTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:47)
    at ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:34)
    at invokeTask (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1540:14)
    at XMLHttpRequest.globalZoneAwareCallback (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1566:17)
```

here is my code

```
  uploadFile() {
    this.http.User_postFileData_withF('signup/upload-signup/' + this.userId, this.uploadData).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
      },
      error => {
        console.log(error)
      },
      () => {
        console.log('upload finish')
      }
    );
  }
```

http method

```
  User_postFileData_withF(url: string, body) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': sessionStorage.getItem("userToken") });
    return this.http.post(this.serverip + url, body, { headers: headers });
  }
```

my html

```
  <input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="changeFile($event)" 

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="uploadFile()">上傳</button>
```

my ts

```
  uploadData = new FormData();

  changeFile(event) {
    var image = event.target.files[0];

    var pattern = /image-*/;
    var reader = new FileReader();

    this.uploadData.append('name', image);
  }
```

thank you

Comment: Share html here.

Comment: This happens when you are sending json and content-type as text. Same applies to server when they set content-type application/json and returning string

Comment: @UnluckyAj I shared my html

Comment: @PratapA.K thank you! i'll try